# Where do I put end_editing() in Pythonista?

Tags: pythonista

I’m making a little pricing tool in Pythonista. Here’s what I wrote.

```
# starts actions with go button
def getPrices(mtmPriceUser):
     viewSelector = mtmPriceUser.superview

     userInput = viewSelector['textview1'].text

     userInput = float(userInput)

     textLabel1 = v['label1']

     discNamesList, discOutcomesdict = creatDiscList(standardDisc, userInput)

     # create string of discounts and prices
     priceString = createString(discNamesList,discOutcomesDict)

     textLabel1.text = priceString

     textLabel1.end_editing()

v = ui.load_view()
v.present('sheet')
```

I get the following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/private/var/mobile/Containers/Shared/AppGroup/7C463C71-C565-47D8-A1D8-C2D588A974C1/Pythonista3/Documents/Pricing App/UI_Attempt.py", line 79, in getPrices
    textLabel1.end_editing()
AttributeError: '_ui.Label' object has no attribute 'end_editing'
```

Where do I use the end editing method?  If I can’t, how else can I get the keyboard to go away after I push the button?

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be calling `end_editing()` on a label, which does not have this method.

You need to call the method on the `TextField` or `TextView` object that was used for data entry.

In your case, this seems to be `viewSelector['textview1']` which might be worth storing in a variable for simplicity, like you do with the label.

For example:

```
text_entry = viewSelector['textview1']
userInput = text_entry.text
# Your other code
text_entry.end_editing()
```